# I do POST request, server receives and logs GET request

Tags: php, android, post, http-post

This in an Android application, Java does a POST request, with php handling it.

**This works fine when working locally**, apache logs a POST:

```
192.168.1.123 - - [29/Mar/2012:15:46:56 +0200] "POST /usuarioLogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 292 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

**When working remotely, apache logs a GET request**, and obviously doesn't find the parameters sent. Apache logs the following:

```
78.XXX.256.XXX - - [29/Mar/2012:16:20:05 +0200] "GET /usuarioLogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 267 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

The java code executing the POST:

```
private void HttpPost(String php, ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String host = com.android.taggies.LoginUser.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.host);
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(host + php);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

And the PHP:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbBaggies");

$q=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as 'return' FROM users
WHERE name='$_POST[user]' AND password ='$_POST[pass]'");

while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
{
    $output[]=$e;
} 

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: If i recall correctly, this is a cross-domain issue with android, which is not capable of doing POST requests to external servers, only GET. I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problems with a POST requests too, to upload an image to my external LAMP server. This really helped me:

http://moazzam-khan.com/blog/?p=490

It's a class with several GET and POST methods. Try using this:

```
public static HttpData post(String sUrl, Hashtable<String, String> ht) throws Exception {
            String key;
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            Enumeration<String> keys = ht.keys();
            while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                    key = keys.nextElement();
                    data.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
                    data.append("=");
                    data.append(URLEncoder.encode(ht.get(key), "UTF-8"));
                    data.append("&amp;");
            }
            return HttpRequest.post(sUrl, data.toString());
    }
```

You will need some external classes I think. Please check the link.